# CSS cascading priority confusion

Tags: css

I'm confused about why the `<h1>` on [this website](http://names.darkgreener.com/) has a `font-family` of `Helvetica` (at least when viewed in Chrome).

From Google Developer Tools, it looks like the font-family is being inherited from the Bootstrap CSS's `body` rule (see [bootstrap.min.css](http://names.darkgreener.com/css/bootstrap.min.css)).

Shouldn't the [names.css](http://names.darkgreener.com/css/names.css) file take priority? That sets a `font-family` of `Lobster` on the `h1` tag explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a selector priority problem: Chrome won't accept the `inherit` property for `font-family` as a fallback. Remove it and you'll get your font as expected.

[The standart says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-family-prop) that `font-family` accepts a list of fonts, *or* the `inherit` special value, but not a mix of the two. I'm fairly sure that if no font is found in the list, it'll fallback to `inherit`, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was tearing my hair out over that one.

Answer (score 1):

When I open that webpage, Chrome gives me a yellow exclamation triangle on that line, so it does not process that CSS font specification.

Did you declare a `@font-face {}`? It looks to me like the font is not installed correctly, because Chrome doesn't know what to do with it.

---

**EDIT:**

Removing the `inherit` solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: Naming fonts that aren't installed doesn't trigger a CSS syntax error, so it's not related to the `@font-face` directive.